# Kubernetes manual certificate renewal - apiserver ceritificate update failed

Tags: ssl-certificate, kubernetes

We have a bare-metal k8 cluster deployed using [Kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray), its certificates are expiring soon.

```
openssl x509 -in /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt -noout -text |grep ' Not '
```

To update certificates, followed given instructions in [official guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/#manual-certificate-renewal).

```
kubeadm certs renew all
```

Then removed manifest files in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/` one by one, but `api-server` did not restart after moving its manifest back to `/etc/kubernetes/manifests`, had to manually restart the node.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53346921/3760216), suggest to restart docker container.

My questions are:

1. What is the most secure way to update certificates (node restart or docker restart).
2. How is the performance impact during this certificate update process?
3. Is there a way to define certificate life time in kubespray installation?

Kubernetes version : 1.18.8
Kubeadm  : v1.18.8
OS : Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

1. Alternatively from temporarily removing its manifest files from /etc/kubernetes/manifests/ and waiting for 20 seconds you can try to restart docker as described in your [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49885636/kubernetes-expired-certificate/53346921#53346921), I've found a similar workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67643559/what-is-the-best-practice-to-rotate-kubernetes-certificates).
2. > When a root CA certificate update is in progress, kubernetes components (apiserver, scheduler, controller-manager, kubelet) and application pods will be restarted. Since the update is a rolling update, system will be functioning as usual but there will be small performance impact during the update. The user should update the host sequentially so the impact can be minimized. https://docs.starlingx.io/specs/specs/stx-6.0/approved/security-2008675-kubernetes-rootca-update.html
3. As per [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/2321) it looks like there is no such way.